# Xcode always set .php as default editor

Tags: php, xcode, macos

Xcode in every update set Xcode default editor for .php files. I have to set the editor I need as the default editor every time. How can I forbid Xcode to do this?

Answer (score 3):

- Open a directory with a `.php` file.
- Right click and choose **Get Info**.
- Click on Xcode.app under **Open with:** [image: Open with]
- Select your choice, I picked TextEdit.app.[image: TextEdit]
- Click **Change All...**
- Hit **Continue**
  [image: Continue]